# How to scale a CCSprite to any resolution in CocosSharp (Android)?

Tags: c#, android, scale, ccsprite, cocossharp

I'm trying to scale a CCSprite to any resolution in CocosSharp, this is what I've got:

```
void AddTruck ()
    {
        var spriteSheet = new CCSpriteSheet ("animations/truck.plist");
        var animationFrames = spriteSheet.Frames.FindAll ((x) => x.TextureFilename.StartsWith ("frame"));

        walkAnim = new CCAnimation (animationFrames, 0.1f);
        walkRepeat = new CCRepeatForever (new CCAnimate (walkAnim));
        truck = new CCSprite (animationFrames.First ()) { Name = "Truck" };
        truck.Scale = 0.70f;

        AddChild (truck);
    }
```

And I want that when its added to scene, it be resized according to the device resolution... Any tips?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I think that in order to do that, you have to have another folder with HD images, and acording to the device resolution, you use 'em... But I did the following, and it worked for me:

```
        float ResTruck(CCSprite sprite)
    {
        float scale = 0.0f;
        float resWid = CCScene.DefaultDesignResolutionSize.Width;
        float resHei = CCScene.DefaultDesignResolutionSize.Height;

        if (resWid > 500)
            scale = 0.70f;
        else if (resWid > 1080)
            scale = 0.90f;
        else if (resWid > 1300)
            scale = 1.0f;


        return scale;
    }
```

And then, I asing the "scale" value to my sprite:

```
            float scale = ResTruck(truck);

        truck.Scale = scale;
```

And that's it :v